# How to use a string as an HtmlAgilityPack Document path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, html-agility-pack

As the question implies, I'm trying to use a string as an HtmlAgilityPack DocumentNode path. When I run the code it says; Illegal characters in path.

My code:

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.IO;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild
{
    public class xlAccount_SCProcess
    {
        public static string ascDir { get; set; }
        public static string ascFav { get; set; }
        public static string accountSourceCodeDir;

        public static void ascRead()
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ascDir);
            ascFav = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"favoritesContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul")[0].InnerHtml;


        }

    }


}
```

Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Dynamic;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild.xlAccount_SCProcess.ascDir = "@" + "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";

            //await Task.Delay(100);
            Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild.xlAccount_SCProcess.ascRead();

            textBox2.Text = Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild.xlAccount_SCProcess.ascFav;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild.xlAccount_SCProcess.ascDir = "@" + "\"" +  textBox1.Text + "\"";

            label1.Text = Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild.xlAccount_SCProcess.ascDir;
        }
    }
}
```

The process is run by ascRead in the namespace Class_xlAccountSCRead_ClassBuild.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by *DocumentNode path*. Is the "Illegal characters" error thrown at the line `doc.Load(ascDir);`? If so, can you post the exact value of `ascDir` at the time the error occur?

Comment: @har07 since OP explicitly adds slash at the end of the value the error is quite expected... Not really sure how it should be fixed so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thought you're right. I tried to confirm by running simple test code, but turned out that `\` at the end of a path triggers `DirectoryNotFoundException` instead. Furthermore, it isn't `\` that OP adds (I'm sure you know this). Anyway, your comment leads me to the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to build the string in the way you would do it using C# string literal, like this :

```
string cs_literal = @"the_actual_path_goes_here";
```

Notice that your code here...

```
string your_string = "@" + "\"" +  textBox1.Text + "\"";
```

...will produce the equivalent of this C# string literal instead :

```
string cs_literal = "@\"the_actual_path_goes_here\"";
```

Having said that, quotes is illegal in path hence the "illegal characters in path" exception. Actually, you don't need all the escaping here since it isn't string literal that you type in C# code. Just pass the string from the `TextBox` *as is*  :

```
string your_string = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks man (or gal), your suggestion fixed my problem. Can't believe it didn't occur me to try that.